# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on my string

Tags: asp.net

hi I have this error" Object reference not set to an instance of an object." In my string constr.
what does it mean?
thanks for answering =)

```
   private void BindGrid()
    {

        string constr = ConfigurationManager 
                    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString; //Error here

        sql = "select * from LogDetails";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

        DataTable t = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(t);

        GridView1.DataSource = t;

        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: You don't have a Connection String with the Key `conString` in your web.config file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add connection string in your web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;UserID=userName;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```